# A model to compare two sets of data to see if they become more similar to eachother

Tags: r, model

Does someone know of a model I can use that will compare two sets of data to see if they *become* more similar to each other as time increases?

I am using the data psid from the library faraway. I'm investigating to see whether the impact of sex on income decreases as the year increases. So I want a model to predict whether the gap between the income decreases.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Cross-Validated. It is not clear from your question what your data set is exactly. Can you clarify what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It is not clear from your post what exactly your data set is, I am assuming for now that it is a sample of salary data grouped by gender and age)

Some thoughts on your question:

- First, what you are dealing with is not a prediction problem, it is a [hypothesis testing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing): You are not trying to guess the value of previously unobserved data. In your case, you already have all the observations, and you are trying to evaluate whether those observations justify a certain statement regarding gender pay gap.

  **(a)** Your data is: A sample of salary figures, grouped by gender and by age.
  **(b)** Your hypothesis is: "That the gender pay gap decreases with age"

  Your question is: Given the data in **(a)**, is the statement in **(b)** justified?

  To further illustrate the difference between hypothesis testing and prediction, here are some examples of prediction problems based on your (assumed) data set:

  1. You have salaries grouped by age and by gender, given a new salary and the age of the recipient, can you accurately predict the gender? This is a classification problem.
  2. You have data about salaries grouped by age and by gender, going up only to age 45. Can you predict what the gender pay gap is for the 55~60 age group? This is a regression problem.
- You say that your data changes over time, but I'm not sure that is accurate. To say that the data changes over time, would be more like: Is the pay gap between genders in 1990 the same as the pay gap between genders in 1970 (And you would be dealing with a time series problem)? In your case, the pay changes over time for each individual in the population, or for each cohort as they grow together in age, but from your perspective, you are looking at a slice of time data spread across different age groups, *not* the data for one cohort spread over different time periods.

To answer your overall post, the type of analysis you are looking for is called an [ANOVA (ANalysis Of VAriance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) study.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I attempted to apply an ANOVA study.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "salary gap between gender" is a continuous variable, then the problem becomes one of linear regression (as a first step !).

SalaryGap ~ b + a*Year

If a is significantly different from zero AND a < 0 then that would add some value to your hypothesis that SalaryGap is decreasing as Year increase.